# Details missing in the camera view

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, camera

I'm working on a book, the problem is that when I see the rendering not from the camera POV, it's possible to see more details, like the shadow between the pages. In the camera view the shadows are missing, and it appears like there is only a bigger page.
Free view:
[image]

The Camera view:

[image]

Actually I'm working on Cycles, GPU Compute enabled and the same problem is present also in the final rendering

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image and share your file?